# List View in TabHost Not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-listview, android-tabhost

I've an application in which i want to show a list view that is displayed with in the tabhost having multiple tabs 
the problem is that 
the code i was using to bind the list view which was working fine when i was not working with tabhost is not working here

my code is

```
<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="600sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_span="3" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="600sp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="top" >
    </TabWidget>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="300sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="40sp"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Notebook_Tab"
            android:layout_width="600sp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/DesktopTabListTableLayout"
                android:layout_width="600sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/DesktopListTableRow"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/DesktopListView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_span="4"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:isScrollContainer="true"
                        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
                        android:scrollbarSize="10sp"
                        android:scrollbars="vertical" >
                    </ListView>
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>                               
    </FrameLayout>
</TabHost>
```

and code

```
public void FillGrid(String s) {
        clsDatabase dbh = new clsDatabase(this);
        dbh.openDataBase();
        Cursor cursor;
        cursor = dbh.getGridData(s);
        dbh.close();
        if (cursor != null) {
            int cnt = cursor.getCount();
            if (cnt > 0) {
                startManagingCursor(cursor);
                try {
                SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.desktop_list, cursor, new String[] {
                   AuditTab.KEY_ROW_ID, AuditTab.KEY_ID,
                             AuditTab.KEY_SHORT_NAME }, new int[] {
                R.id.txt_Desktop_ID, R.id.txt_DesktopID,
                R.id.txt_DesktopModel });
                adapter.setViewResource(R.layout.desktop_list);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
                lv.setFocusable(false);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.fillInStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

The above function was working well when there was no tabhost but now it is not working and also there is no problem is getGridData() method rows are returning well but data is not binded by the adapter there are no any id related problem every thing is as it is as it should be Please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first bound the content of layout and then bind it with tab it will work